# web response always returns error 500

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, asmx

I am trying to do a small app to test a web service using .net framework.
I always get error 500 from the server.

here are my codes 
first the server side code

```
public class BalanceInquiry : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string getAccount(string accNbr)
    {
        return accNbr;
    }
}
```

Here is my client side code:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        //creating object of program class to access methods  
        Program obj = new Program();  
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Input values..");  
        //Reading input values from console  
        string a =(Console.ReadLine());  
       // int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  
        //Calling InvokeService method  
        obj.InvokeService(a); 

    }  
    public void InvokeService(string a )  
    {  
        //Calling CreateSOAPWebRequest method  
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();  

        XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();  
        //SOAP Body Request  
        SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>  
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
         <soap:Body>  
            <getAccount xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">  
              <accNbr>" + a + @"</accNbr>  
            </getAccount>  
          </soap:Body>  
        </soap:Envelope>");  


        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())  
        {
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                stmw.Write(SOAPReqBody);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            //Geting response from request  
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        }

        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        }
        Console.Read();

    }  

    public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()  
    {  
        //Making Web Request  
        HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:62325/BalanceInquiry.asmx");  
        //SOAPAction  
        Req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction:http://tempuri.org/");  
        //Content_type  
        Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";  
        Req.Accept = "text/xml";  
        //HTTP method  
        Req.Method = "POST";  
        //return HttpWebRequest  
        return Req;  
    }  
}
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H95da.png)

the error is

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at consumeWebSer.Program.InvokeService(String a) in C:\Users\msaliba\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\consumeWebSer\consumeWebSer\Program.cs:line 53

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this error. Is it something in my code or it could be something else?

Comment: As for _every_ error 500 ever: Inspect the error details on the server.

Comment: Please post these error messages as text, not an image, as it makes it much easier to search and copy-paste.

Comment: The SOAPAction is set to `Addition`, the actual SOAP body has `HelloWorld` as arguments, yet the server method is `getAccount`. As long as the three don't match this will never work.

Comment: sorry i will change it .. but the problem  still showing

Comment: how can i check the detail on the server ?

Comment: @michel one option, if it is a windows server, you check the event log in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use SOAP with WebApi, which is way more fit for REST implementations; usually you would want to go with WCF if SOAP is a requirement.

Anyway your client is sending an xml, but I don't see the part where your service parses it to extract the `accNbr` parameter, nor I see `accNbr` in the above-mentioned xml.

Also, I'm not sure whether your `getAccount` method is exposed as a Post method.

Comment: I didn't post the whole code because it never pass the web response.
I am doing a small test, I have a bigger project that i need to use soap .

Comment: Yes, of course it doesn' pass the web response on the client: the error happens on the server, where your web service should parse the xml. Does your web service parse the xml? Can you add some code to do it in 'getAccount' ?

Also, I don't see where you are calling 'getAccount' from your client: perhaps you should add it to the address in 'CreateSOAPWebRequest' , as in 'http://localhost:62325/BalanceInquiry.asmx/getAccount'.

Moreover, if you use webapi and you expose a Post method, you should name it e.g. PostGetAccount to make it work, i.e. using a "Post" suffix.

Comment: i don't have to parse the xml in the server . well i am calling it in the xml part

Comment: I think you are expecting webapi (which is Rest) to do the xml parsing for you. Do you? I don't think that comes out of the box, but you must do it on your own... Wcf does it automatically, but you are not using it, right?

Comment: well i am i little bit confused . i don't really know what should i do . 
i want to create a web service and  consume it within a client .

Comment: File->New->Project, then choose WCF Service Application (C#); that will be your service. Then create the client and don't worry about the xml anymore, you will have Intellisense for every web service method. If you try this and find any problems, write here and we'll get by.

Comment: well I have used WCF before, but the thing is that there are some prebuilt web services. I just want to build some test web services to use them with client side. I dont want to change the web service type

Comment: That's fair; but those prebuilt services are... Soap? Rest? Have you got any specifics? Perhaps a Wsdl file? Did they ask you a Soap (xml) message?